# Cannot convert type 'byte' to 'T'

Tags: c#, generics, casting

am new with C# so i really dont know how to make it , but in C++ i was doing it like this

```
template <typename T> writeInt(int location, T value){
    *(T*)&buffer[location] = value;
}
```

in C# am trying to do the same

```
public void WriteInt<T>(int location,T value)
        {
            (T)buffer[location] = value;
        }
```

but am geting this error `Cannot convert type 'byte' to 'T'`
so how can i do it, thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is `T`? What is `buffer[]`? It looks like you may need to stick to C++ or realign your views on what is normal in C#!

Comment: @David Heffernan  so i can say WriteInt<Uint16> or 32 etc , buffer = byte[]

Comment: Did you take a look at Generics in C# (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(VS.80).aspx)?

Answer (score 5):

Firstly,

You should probably be using a `MemoryStream` and a `BinaryWriter` to write primitive types to a buffer. You can, as suggested, use the `BitConverter` class, but you'll end up with a lot of intermediate `byte[]` objects going that way.

```
byte[] buffer;

int value1 = 10;
double value2 = 20;
string value3 = "foo";

using(var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
    using(var writer = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(ms))
    {
        writer.Write(value1);
        writer.Write(value2);
        writer.Write(value3);
    }
}

buffer = ms.ToArray();
```

(`value1`, `value2`, and `value3` are just examples here to show you a couple of the various overloads available; you should look at [the MSDN page on BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) for more information)

More importantly,

You're using pointer arithmetic in your C++ code; C# only provides true pointer functionality when running within an `unsafe` block, and you should avoid that if at all possible (which it is here). .NET works on references, not pointers, so you don't have as much control over the actual memory allocation.

To make a long story short, you can't do what you're trying to do in the way you're trying to do it.

Answer (score 2):

To do what you want, I believe you'll need to do something like this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192] ;
void WriteInt<T>( int offset , T value)
{
  Type       tBitConvert = typeof(BitConverter) ;
  MethodInfo getBytes    = tBitConvert.GetMethod( "GetBytes" ,
                             BindingFlags.Static|BindingFlags.Public ,
                             Type.DefaultBinder , new Type[]{ typeof(T) } ,
                             null 
                             ) ;

  if ( getBytes == null ) throw new InvalidOperationException("invalid type") ;

  byte[] octets = (byte[]) getBytes.Invoke(null, new object[]{ value } ) ;

  Array.Copy( octets , 0 , buffer , offset , octets.Length ) ;
  return ;
}
```

But I think you you'd be better off — certainly more idiomatic — if you simply used `System.IO.BinaryStream`, subtyping it to provide the buffering you appear to want.

Comment: Points for inventiveness, but I don't think it's necessarily wise to point someone who's new to .NET (and is simply trying to do something in the way they're used to) down a path like this.

Comment: Hence my suggestion to just use a `BinaryStream`.

Answer (score 0):

> so i can say WriteInt or 32
>   etc , buffer = byte[]

What you have would not be allowed in either case.

If **buffer** is a *byte array* then you need to covert **value** to a byte array instead.